# Inverse eigenvalue of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

T is a linear transformation, and $\lambda$ is N eigenvalue of T. How do I prove that $\lambda^{-1}$ is an eigenvalue for $T^{-1}$?

I know for a matrix, I can use the fact that $Av=\lambda v$, but how does a linear transformation work?

Comment: Do you have to prove it for a specific 2 by 2 or 3 by 3 or do you have to prove it generally for an n by n matrix?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/572429/if-a-is-invertible-prove-that-lambda-neq-0-and-vecv-is-also-an-eigenv/572438#572438

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If $\lambda\ne0$ *(and we know that the eigenvalues of an invertible matrix are different of $0$)* then
$$Av=\lambda v\iff A^{-1}A v=A^{-1}\lambda v\iff \frac{1}{\lambda }v=A^{-1} v$$
hence $\frac{1}{\lambda }$ is an eigenvalue for $A^{-1}$.

Comment: Ok, you are a quicker typer than me, hence an upvote...

Answer (score 4):

As $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $\textbf T$, $\textbf Tv=\lambda v$ for some $\lambda$.  Therefore $\textbf T^{-1} \textbf Tv=\textbf T^{-1}\lambda v$ or $v=\lambda \textbf T^{-1} v$.  It follows $\textbf T^{-1}v=\lambda^{-1}v$

Linear transformations, as they were taught to me take "lines to lines".  In $\mathbb{F}^n$, this means all vectors are transformed continuously under the rules that, if $t$ is the linear transformation and $\vec v\in\mathbb{F}^n$, then $t(\lambda \vec v)=\lambda t(\vec v)$ and $t(\vec v+\vec w)=t(\vec v)+t(\vec w)$ for all $\lambda\in \mathbb{F}$, $\vec w\in \mathbb{F}^n$.  You can prove from this information that $t$ can be written as a matrix transformation (try it yourself!).

Answer (score 2):

For any linear transformation $f$ on a finite dimensional vector space, there is a matrix such that for all $x$, $f(x)=Ax$.

You don't even need this. The proof works the same with $f$.